# Razorpay .then not called sometimes

Tags: reactjs, react-native, razorpay

I am using react-native-razorpay to accept payment and sometimes .then method is not called for some users. Please help to debug this issue. Also this happens for 30% of our users. Following is the code I am using.

```
let options = {
    description: 'Pay Fee',
    currency: 'INR',
    key: 'my key is here',
    amount: data?.amount * 100,
    name: 'Sample App',
    prefill: {
    email: profileData?.Email ?? '',
    contact: profileData?.ContactNo ?? '',
    name: profileData?.StudentName ?? '',
    },
    theme: {color: colors.green},
};

RazorpayCheckout.open(options)
.then(response => {
}))
```

Comment: I mean... typically when the first callback to .then isn't called, the second is. Potentially with information on why the first didn't get called. Error handling.

Comment: @KevinB The error method is also not called. When I check the dashboard for corresponding payment, it shows success.

Comment: it doesn't have anything for us to work with. You're calling a method, and getting no output and no error handling, and based on your comments, no error. there's nothing for us to do here?

Answer (score -1):

To get more information add a catch and finally

```
RazorpayCheckout.open(options)
.then(response => {
})
.catch(e) {
 console.log(e);
}
.finally() {
 console.log(‘finally’);
}
```